# LiveBindings work in Designtime, but not RunTime

Tags: delphi, sqlite, delphi-10.1-berlin, livebindings

I am working on my first multi-platform app for Windows and MacOSX. I decided to go with SQLite, and a StringGrid to check connectivity. I have placed all necessary components on the form from looking at an SQLite Sample that came with Delphi 10.0.

I ran the LiveBindings Wizard connecting my FDTable to the StringGrid just fine. I can activate the table and it displays my data (imported from a BatchMove), see attachment. But when I run the app, connect my FDConnection and my Table, the grid doesn't get populated. What am I missing?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am facing this problem.
Dataset sometimes lose value at runtime.
I solved this shortcoming with a line of code after the opening of such datasets

```
BindSourceGPS.DataSet:=TransTable;
```

Grigore

Comment: Please elaborate and be specific your question. you should read how to ask a good question [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Similar problems used to occur (maybe 10-15 years ago) with  flakey 3rd-party db-aware components.  It seemed likely that the problem was caused by the component raising an exception in the IDE which its code silenced.  If you manage to come up with a reproducible test case (which in these circs is very hard) then post it here as a q.  Meanwhile, your work-around is the only solution, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry folks. Answered my own question. I had everything on a Dataform and that was being created first. I thought I had it running, but all of the examples I was looking at the data components were kept on the main form. And since I can hide non-visible components, I moved everything to the main form.

But, I forgot to change the form creation order. Moved the main form to be created first and Whala. Everything is working. Still not sure why having the data components and livebinding on separate forms worked in preview but not while running, but everything on one form, created first works just fine for me.

Comment: It should presumably work from a data module, so long as that data module is created before the form.